# How do I read the content of a span class with python playwright

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I want to read the score from a webpage. The score is located in:

```
<span _ngcontent-fnp-c148="" class="score"> &nbsp;<!--bindings={
"ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--> 96%, </span>
```

Here the result would be "96%"

I'd like to either search for the classname "score" directly, or if it's necessary dump the entire page html into a string and search for it manually.
An approach to do either would be fine.

I'm using python playwright, but I assume the methods should be similar to the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Page.innerText(".score")](https://playwright.dev/#path=docs%2Fapi.md&q=pageinnertextselector-options) method to accomplish that, see here for an example:

```
// @ts-check
const playwright = require("playwright");

(async () => {
  const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch();
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();
  await page.setContent(`
    <span _ngcontent-fnp-c148="" class="score"> &nbsp;<!--bindings={
"ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--> 96%, </span>
`);
  const content = await page.innerText(".score")
  console.log(content)
  await page.screenshot({ path: `example.png` });
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Or interactively here: https://try.playwright.tech/?s=bl1fed4

For Python usage see here: https://microsoft.github.io/playwright-python/sync_api.html#playwright.sync_api.Page.innerText

Comment: May I ask why these are labeled with a "." at the front?

Comment: @ValentinMetz these are CSS selectors. They are used to identify and find elements on the page, see here for more information: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 2):

The [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65095394/6243352) is useful, but happens to be in JS rather than Python.

Here's how you can do this in Python:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright  # 1.37.0


html = """<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<span _ngcontent-fnp-c148="" class="score"> &nbsp;<!--bindings={
"ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--> 96%, </span>
</body></html>"""

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.set_content(html)
    text = (
        page.locator("[_ngcontent-fnp-c148]")
            .text_content()
            .strip()
            .strip(",")
    )
    print(text)
    browser.close()
```

The selector `.score` is also possible, but which to use depends on which of the two options is more unique on the page which can't be determined by the single element provided.

> ...or if it's necessary dump the entire page html into a string

This is almost never necessary. The primary time to resort to raw strings is when you run out of HTML tags to work with. At that point, the final text content can be processed a bit further as done here, stripping out whitespace and punctuation.